# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined - Wordpress specific issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, undefined

So I've been trying to implement this script in a WordPress site I've been working on, but it keeps throwing the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle_visibility is not defined` and I'm not entirely sure why as it works outside of WordPress according to other people. I've had some issues before with scripts in WordPress such as the $ needing to be swapped with jQuery etc, but I've been unsuccessful so far solving this. Basically I just need it to toggle `display:block/none` on two divs when the corresponding links are clicked.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}

<div id="choose-membership">
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visability('ms-membership-wrapper-202');">Click here for free membership</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visability('ms-membership-wrapper-213');">Click here for Paid membership</a>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Misspelled function. Function is `toggle_visibility` you put `toggle_visability` in your HTML.

```
<div id="choose-membership">
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('ms-membership-wrapper-202');">Click here for free membership</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('ms-membership-wrapper-213');">Click here for Paid membership</a>    
</div>
```

Comment: Ha oh dear, thats so embarrassing! Thanks for pointing that out, i clearly need more tea [caffeine] this morning!

Answer (score 4):

Your `onclick` event has a typo:

```
onclick="toggle_visability('ms-membership-wrapper-202');"
```

Should be:

```
onclick="toggle_visibility('ms-membership-wrapper-202');"
```

Give that a go :)

Comment: Ha oh dear, thats so embarrassing! Thanks for pointing that out, i clearly need more tea [caffeine] this morning!

Comment: @Moose A cup of coffee is how I start my day - we've all done it ;)